# incorrect compiz config settings

Tags: compiz

I wanted to use `ccsm` (`Compiz Config Settings Manager`) to make the appearance of my desktop and windows look more cool. But after some changes, the windows snap to the screen instead of the launcher and the title bar when first created, like the windows below. Also, the windows manager won't automatically manage the place of the windows now.

[image: nautilus]

[image: evince]

How can I fix this problem, because with the title bar hidden, it is hard to use unless you move it out using <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch `ccsm` and check your settings in <kbd>**Window Management**</kbd> > <kbd>**Place Windows**</kbd>.

The plugin must be **enabled** (check the option <kbd>Enable Place Windows</kbd> in the left bar). I can reproduce your described behaviour when I disable this plugin.

I recommend to also set its <kbd>Placement Mode</kbd> option to <kbd>Smart</kbd>, but that's just a suggestion, the other might also look nice.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by resetting everything to its original value.

From [Ubuntuhandbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/reset-unity-and-compiz-settings-in-ubuntu-14-04/):

You can reset compiz with the following command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Then, reset Unity, using:

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: No need to nuke all the settings, it's probably just a disabled "Place Windows" plugin that causes the problem.

Comment: @ByteCommander - Yeah! you are probably right.